# Google sheets if with array formula

Tags: syntax, google-sheets

I'm trying to paste a column from one sheet to another under the condition it contains a given value, in my example: 816.  I tried this but doesnt work.

```
=if(arrayformula(Data Sheet!C:C)=816,"816")
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Filter function?

```
=filter('Data Sheet'!C:C,'Data Sheet'!C:C=816)
```

Answer (score -1):

`ISNUMBER(MATCH())` is the easiest way to check if a value is part of a range.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(816, 'Data Sheet'!C:C, 0)), 'Data Sheet'!C:C, ""))
```

Comment: This is displaying every cell in the column not just the ones with the value 816.

Comment: Oh, in that case you want to use filter like user3626750 suggested